# Convert List<object> to List<MyEnumType> with MyEnumType in Type variable

Tags: c#, list, parsing, enums

I want to convert a `List<string>` to `List<MyEnum>`.

The problem is, if I parse all items of `List<string>` to `MyEnum`, the new list will stay as `List<object>`.

```
static void ConvertList(List<string> stringList, Type enumType)
{
    var enumList = stringList.Select(a => Enum.Parse(enumType, a)).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Original Type: " + typeof(List<MyEnum>));
    Console.WriteLine("EnumList Type: " + enumList.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine("EnumList First Element Type: " + enumList.First().GetType());
    Console.Read();
}

// Console.Out
// Original Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication1.MyEnum]
// EnumList Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]
// EnumList First Element Type: ConsoleApplication1.MyEnum
```

Is it possible to convert the list to `List<MyEnum>` just by a `Type` variable?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Thanks for your help.

But I need to clarify that the enum type is ONLY stored in an instance of `Type`. Thanks!

I can't call something like `ConvertList<MyEnum>`.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to say, that the stringList does not contain each enum value. Just some of them. But thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Do you care about invalid cast exceptions?

Comment: This is just an example. ;) Anyway, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is reflection, but it's ugly.

```
    static object ConvertList<T>(List<string> stringList)
    {
        return stringList.Select(a => (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), a)).ToList();
    }

    static object ConvertList(List<string> stringList, Type enumType)
    {
        var method = new Func<List<string>, object>(ConvertList<object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        return method.MakeGenericMethod(enumType).Invoke(null, new object[] { stringList });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats just the perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this,

```
static void ConvertList<T>(List<string> stringList)
{
    var enumList = stringList.Select(a => (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), a)).ToList();
}
```

And call the method,

```
 ConvertList<MyEnum>(new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2" });
```

**Update**

Changing the calling mechanism can help in this case,

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("ConvertList", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var type = typeof (MyEnum);
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
generic.Invoke(null, new[] {new List<string> {"Value1", "Value2"}});
```

Comment: Will not work in this case, because the enumType is stored in an instance of `Type`. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Jan What are you talking about? There's no such thing as instance of `Type` in your code.

Comment: MyEnum is in another library, that is referenced at runtime.